# Compiling Linux creates corrupted object files

Tags: linux, installation, linux-kernel, compile

I'm trying to update my current system to Linux 5.4.85. I have two toolchains that support compiling this kernel: gcc 4.6.3 and gcc 10.2.1. The compilation fails with both.

I downloaded and extracted the tar ball, ran `make menuconfig`, saved the configuration, ran `make` and `make CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-musl-`. With the latter, I tried to invoke the newer toolchain, as `x86_64-linux-musl-gcc` is the 10.2.1 gcc and the other tools are present in $PATH.

Output is either

```
.
.
.


  VDSO2C  arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-image-64.c
  CC      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-image-64.o
  LDS     arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/vdso32.lds
  CC      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/vclock_gettime.o
  AS      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/note.o
  AS      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/system_call.o
  AS      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/sigreturn.o
  VDSO    arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32.so.dbg
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32.so
  VDSO2C  arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-image-32.c
  CC      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-image-32.o
  AR      arch/x86/entry/vdso/built-in.a
  CC      arch/x86/entry/vsyscall/vsyscall_64.o
objdump: arch/x86/entry/vsyscall/vsyscall_64.o: File format not recognized
  AS      arch/x86/entry/vsyscall/vsyscall_emu_64.o
  AR      arch/x86/entry/vsyscall/built-in.a
  AS      arch/x86/entry/entry_64.o
objdump: arch/x86/entry/entry_64.o: File format not recognized
  AS      arch/x86/entry/thunk_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o
objdump: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o: File format not recognized
  CC      arch/x86/entry/common.o
objdump: arch/x86/entry/common.o: File format not recognized
  AS      arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.o
  CC      arch/x86/entry/syscall_32.o
  AR      arch/x86/entry/built-in.a
  CC      arch/x86/events/amd/core.o
objdump: arch/x86/events/amd/core.o: File format not recognized
  CC      arch/x86/events/amd/uncore.o
objdump: arch/x86/events/amd/uncore.o: File format not recognized
  CC      arch/x86/events/amd/ibs.o
objdump: arch/x86/events/amd/ibs.o: File format not recognized
  CC      arch/x86/events/amd/iommu.o
objdump: arch/x86/events/amd/iommu.o: File format not recognized
  AR      arch/x86/events/amd/built-in.a
  CC      arch/x86/events/intel/core.o
objdump: arch/x86/events/int
```

Or, with the newer toolchain

```
.
.
.


include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/main.o
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/main.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/main.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: init/main.o: file format not recognized
  CC      init/version.o
  CC      init/do_mounts.o
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: init/do_mounts.o: file format not recognized
  CC      init/do_mounts_rd.o
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts_rd.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts_rd.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: init/do_mounts_rd.o: file format not recognized
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts_initrd.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts_initrd.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: init/do_mounts_initrd.o: file format not recognized
  CC      init/do_mounts_md.o
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts_md.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: warning: init/do_mounts_md.o has a corrupt section with a size (7472747368732e00) larger than the file size
x86_64-linux-musl-objdump: init/do_mounts_md.o: file format not recognized
  CC      init/initramfs.o
```

How can I compile a modern Linux kernel on my system?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your elfutils pkg.

Comment: Explaining how to do this, or why this is the likely cause, would go a long way towards making this a better answer. Right now is it just a comment.

Comment: worked for me, my elf version was 0.176 upgrading it to 0..188 fixed the issue